# un botón que al darle "click" se elimine este mismo y ejecute las funciones de un juego con JavaScript, el tiempo corre bien pero que inicie lo demas

Tags: javascript, html

este es el código HTML, pero la cosa es que utilizando el input se borre el mismo input y comience a correr el juego, ya que he utilizado algunas formas pero no me sale como debe ya que al darle en las fichas están se mueven sin la necesidad de darles click en el input. Les agradecería mucho si me ayudan con esto, ya que no he podido solucionarlo ese detalle.

````
<html>
<head>
    <title>Juego</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styless.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1 class="Titulo">Rompecabezas SENA</h1>
<svg id="entorno" width="600" height="600" class="fondoatras">
    <g id="fondo"><image href="./img/img_rompe2.png" width="384" height="478" x="100" y="100" id="imagen"></g>
<g class="padre" id="0"><image href="./img/01.png" class="movil"> </g>
<g class="padre" id="1"><image href="./img/02.png" class="movil"> </g>
<g class="padre" id="2"><image href="./img/03.png" class="movil"> </g>
<g class="padre" id="3"><image href="./img/04.png" class="movil"> </g>
<g class="padre" id="4"><image href="./img/05.png" class="movil"> </g>
<g class="padre" id="5"><image href="./img/06.png" class="movil"> </g>
<g class="padre" id="6"><image href="./img/07.png" class="movil"> </g>
<g class="padre" id="7"><image href="./img/08.png" class="movil"> </g>
<g class="padre" id="8"><image href="./img/09.png" class="movil"> </g>
<g class="padre" id="9"><image href="./img/10.png" class="movil"> </g>
<g class="padre" id="10"><image href="./img/11.png" class="movil"> </g>
<g class="padre" id="11"><image href="./img/12.png" class="movil"> </g>
<g class="padre" id="12"><image href="./img/13.png" class="movil"> </g>
<g class="padre" id="13"><image href="./img/14.png" class="movil"> </g>
<g class="padre" id="14"><image href="./img/15.png" class="movil"> </g>
<g class="padre" id="15"><image href="./img/16.png" class="movil"> </g>
<g class="padre" id="16"><image href="./img/17.png" class="movil"> </g>
<g class="padre" id="17"><image href="./img/18.png" class="movil"> </g>
<g class="padre" id="18"><image href="./img/19.png" class="movil"> </g>
<g class="padre" id="19"><image href="./img/20.png" class="movil"> </g>-->
</svg>

<div id="cronometro">
  <div id="reloj" class="relo">
       00 00
    </div>
  <form name="cron" action="#" id="boton02">
    <input type="button" value="Play" name="boton1" class="boton0" id="boton03">
   </form>
</div>

<audio id="win" src="audio/mario_bros.mp3"></audio>
<script src="js/java_fichas.js"></script>

</body>
</html>```


[![Imagen del juego][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJuVw.jpg
````

Comment: supongo que la funcion de poder moverse a las fichas, debes llamarla despues de borrar el input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok no sé de qué forma estás ejecutando el juego, pero para borrar el botón puedes utilizar el método remove().

```js
const button = document.querySelector("#button");

button.addEventListener("click", e => {
  button.remove();
  
  //funcionQueEjecutaElJuego()
 });
```

```html
<input id="button" type="button" value="Start" />
```